# EF Core Migration Timestamp has wrong time(zone)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an EF Core Code First Project and use EF Core 3.1.0-preview2.19525.5.
When I create a new migration with **Add-Migration**, the timestamp is one hour in the past.

Example 20191110**1739**16_MickeyMouse.cs is a migration I created today at **18:39**

My machine an English Windows 10 device based in Germany and the timezone is configured to UTC+1 (Amsterdam, Berlin, ...)

Not that this a problem at all, but I am just wondering. Where does the timestamp come from? I would expect just the developer's local time.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but sounds like the timestamp in the migration class name is the UTC datetime.

You can verify this by changing your pc's timezone to UTC+2 and create a new migration. I expect the timestamp to be 2 hours ahead of that timezone.

Comment: Confirmed. I switched to Kabul Time (+4:30 Local Time 00:30+1) and got a timestamp of today 20:00. So it's definitely UTC Time, but I wonder what this is mentioned nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp isn't in UTC is it? That would make sense as it would enable developers in different geographical locations to work on a project without migrations being done in the wrong order because one was done, for example, four hours after a previous migration but in a timezone that would stamp the file as ahead of the previous migration.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but is there a reference for this?

Comment: @NedFlanders I suppose there is no reference. It's a default implementation of the IMigrationsIdGenerator interface and you can check it here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsIdGenerator.cs

Comment: Nice find @YuriyRozhovetskiy straight to the source.